# Drupal LDAP to access edir in Novell

Tags: drupal, ldap, novell

i would need assistance on how to configure LDAP in Drupal to connect to the Novell host. I have the parameters but i don't know how to use them. These are the steps i have made:

1. First i installed LDAP module for drupal
2. I enabled most of the LDAP
3. I went to server config but i'm lost.
4. Created the custom page.tpl i want to connect.

The Novell LDAP has an IP address and the web page is in another host. The only thing i want to do is that the Novell ask me the user and password when i access that page.tpl in drupal. Is it possible to achieve that? I would be grateful for your help. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Connection with LDAP can be authorized and not authorized. If authorized, you must specify connection parameters **user name** and **password**  to enter ldap.
I do not know Drupal and how to do it.